# How to show anchor tag from database in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show anchor tag from the database to view but it shows double quotes on anchor tag in view. Below text is in the database.

```
<a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a>
```

And in view, I am trying to show like below

```
foreach (var i in Model.Where(a => a.ParentMenu.Equals(ParentMenu)))
{
  @i.MenuName
}
```

After page loading, it shows it as text like below with double quotes

```
 "<a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a>"
```

I want to convert it in html so that it can show link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below. I hope it will work for you. Thanks

```
@Html.Raw(@i.MenuName)
```